# Software for Network Infrastructure Discovery

Tags: networking, network-monitor

Which software is the best for create a network map in ubuntu? I have bachelor thesis in college, theme is Network Infrastructure Discovery. I must create a network map, automatic discover devices on network in my college. The aim of this work is to describe methods of discovering devices on the local network and then create a map of computer network Constantine The Philosopher University in Nitra. Map network must be designed so that it can be continuously updated and edited. Software can work on Windows or Ubuntu. Format may be generated to export on Google Earth. Should contain computers, laptops, switches, routers, printers in network. Software like op manager, solarwinds NPM, prtg network monitor, lanstate pro, anturis in Windows, cheops-ng, opennms in Ubuntu.

Comment: please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information. Your question is too broad, it does not give any requiremnents that cannot also be found through Google.

Comment: Stanislav, you should point out your requirements explicitly. OK, it should run on Linux obviously. But what services should be discovered? What format should the output generated in? What details should it contain? These are the first 3 things coming to my mind in this connection – there might be other things relevant to you. The better you point them out, the better the answers can match what you're after :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you need with [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) in a few lines:

One of the examples, for traceroute but you can also scan your local network to find out what is there:

```
res,unans = traceroute(["www.microsoft.com","www.cisco.com","www.yahoo.com","www.wanadoo.fr","www.pacsec.com"],dport=[80,443],maxttl=20,retry=-2)

Received 190 packets, got 190 answers, remaining 10 packets
   193.252.122.103:443 193.252.122.103:80 198.133.219.25:443 198.133.219.25:80  207.46...
1  192.168.8.1         192.168.8.1        192.168.8.1        192.168.8.1        192.16...
2  82.251.4.254        82.251.4.254       82.251.4.254       82.251.4.254       82.251...
3  213.228.4.254       213.228.4.254      213.228.4.254      213.228.4.254      213.22...
[...]
res.graph()                          # piped to ImageMagick's display program. Image below.
res.graph(type="ps",target="| lp")   # piped to postscript printer
res.graph(target="> /tmp/graph.svg") # saved to file
```

Gives:
[image]